# How to find the key in firebase database if value is known?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I first want to check which node has the current user's userid. This step works fine. It gives the correct value. Then next, I want to search in that node (either 1 or 2) to find which userid inside that node has a child named "type" which has a value "driver". I want to find the userid that has type="driver".

The current code is

```
mDatabaseReference  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
busReference = mDatabaseReference.child("Busno");
mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
assert mUser != null;
userid = mUser.getUid();


busReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            usercount = ds.getChildrenCount();
            for(int i = 1; i <= usercount; i++){
                if(ds.hasChild(userid)){
                    busno = ds.getKey();
                    driverReference = mDatabaseReference.child("Busno").child(busno);

                    driverReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for(DataSnapshot ds1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                                // I need help in this place.

                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
                    });
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
});
```

[image: My database]

Comment: Have you found the answer? If not, I will post mine.

Comment: @UmarZaii please post your answer

Answer (score 0):

To get the child key try:

```
ds1.getKey();
```

Comment: but i want the child key which has a child named type which value should be "driver" not "parent". So, i just want the driver's userid

Comment: @AjayReal do this logic, get ds1 type and check if is driver, if yes get key else do nothing something like that :
**String type= ds1.child("type").getValue(String.class); 

if(type.equals("driver")){
 //get key
 }**

Answer (score 0):

Use a query to look up the driver:

```
DatabaseReference busRef = ds.getRef(); // no need to rebuild this ref, but I'd recommend rename ds to something more meaningful
Query driverQuery = busRef.orderByKey("type").equalTo("driver");
driverQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {        
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot driverSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(driverSnapshot.getKey());
        }
    }
    ...
```

This will work, but I recommend seriously rethinking your data structure. Make use of the data model of your domain, to come up with an efficient structure that allows for your use-cases.

For example: if a bus can only have a single driver, why not sure the driver as a property of each bus as a top-level collection:

```
drivers: {
  "1": "mlxMu..."
}
```

With that you can directly look up the driver, instead of having to query for them:

```
Query driverRef = ref.getChild("drivers").getChild(busno);
driverQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {        
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
    }
    ...
```

In fact with this data structure, it's probably very feasible to simple keep the list of `drivers` in memory and avoid the nested listener. This drastically improves the readability/maintainability of your code.